# Camera X flash turning off after clicking picture using takepicture() method

Tags: android, android-camerax

So in some phones like Lenovo, and Xiomi Mi A2 when i enable torch mode through preview.enableTorch(true)

and when i click picture through imageCapture.takePicture() the torch light turns off and for subsequent picture clicks it remains turned off.

I want to use takePicture() with flash turned on but its not working in some of LEGACY_HARDWARE phones.

I am using CameraX alpha06 library.